# JS can't calculate 2 values

Tags: javascript

Code can't calculate 2 values in ForEach:

```
                        var total = parseFloat(row[0].price);                       
                        x.forEach(function(j) {
                            var price = 1;
                            total = parseFloat(total + price);
                            console.log(total);
                            })
                        })
```

ForEach loops 10 times, so `total` should be 10 at the end of the loop. How to make `total` to count?

Comment: can you load the full load with JSfiddle? Is something an array? do you get a console error?

Comment: What is `something`? What is the result you're getting?

Comment: There's no purpose whatsoever to `parseFloat` there. `parseFloat` is (as the name suggests) for *parsing* a string into a floating-point number.

Comment: The question is flat out wrong and not specific enough. Javascript _can_ calculate two values in a foreach loop... There is no limit in programming for that. Its a strange question. And finding out what `something` is might be your answer, as in what you pass to `parseFloat` will influence your outcvome. `parseFloat('text')` should result in `NaN` for example.

Comment: Assuming there are 10 things in the outer `something`, even though there's no good reason for `parseFloat` there, the above will work. You should replace the `parseFloat` with simply `total += price`, but...

Comment: `ForEach loops 10 times` - prove it with code. Also you can just do `total += 1` instead of `var price = 1; total = parseFloat(total + price)` in fact, if something is an array, you don't need the forEach loop at all ... total = something.length

Comment: Result is 1. If I set `price` `5`, it will output `5`.

Comment: the **big** question is .. WHAT IS SOMETHING

Comment: `total += price` is not working too.

Comment: WHAT DOES YOUR `something` ARRAY LOOK LIKE? Sorry for the shouting but this question has been asked _multiple_ times and is crucial to finding a solution, or at least, the problem.

Comment: @somethinghere - you should know, what something is :p

Comment: Does it matter? It loops 10 times, it doesnt have effect to `total` and `price` at all.

Comment: it clearly does not loop 10 times - why do you think it loops 10 times?

Comment: @JaromandaX Ha, that is _true_, but I'm not omnipotent. To the OP: I have tested your code and it works when I replace your array with an array of length 10. Also, _if we dont know how your array looks how can we be sure you didnt just use an empty array???_

Comment: Because it outputs total 10 times?

Comment: @ArnasA. You are not being very helpful to people who are trying to help you. -1

Comment: that WHOLE piece of code may be called 10 times then

Comment: it's a simple question **what is something** ... yes, it does matter, the fate of the cheerleader depends on it

Comment: is it the same something as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826426/js-foreach-sometimes-not-executing

Comment: @JaromandaX I sense a pattern. :)

Comment: price !== prices ... i.e. you declare `var price` and you add `prices`

Comment: Sorry, I left mistake in this code.

Comment: Sigh, @ArnasA. , what the hell are we supposed to do with this? We asked for the array and you give us code we cannot execute? We want to know _what array you are using foreach on_, so whatever data is _returned_ from your query should be posted in your post, not _how_ you get it (unless the question is about that). We can't duplicate or debug anything with this.

Comment: I have mysql insert here, and it works fine, it puts everything in mysql, but only this total is not working.

Comment: @ArnasA. for crying out loud man,  we want to know what result your `forEach` is operating on. It makes a _lot_ of difference whether your array looks like `[undefined,undefined]` or `[1,2,3]`, or even if you accidentally got an object back `{key:value}` - that last one won't even run a `forEach` as it is not an array. The issue is that we have to keep asking questions while the answer to it is simple: show us the array you are _working_ with. WE dont have access to your database or data, nor your HTML, so we _need_ to see the **output** from your query.

Comment: You can check this: http://imgur.com/TNOm7Z0

Comment: First goes item name, then price, and then total. But as you can see, price is not being added to total.

Comment: Okay, good luck mate. This is not at all helping anyone, you probably downvoted the only answer that was trying to help you because it didn't apply to your situation, but your answers are unhelpful. You will have to debug the array you get back from your mySQL query and then see that the array is incorrect all along before this will ever work. You'll also learn that the answer given below is actually quite good for all the assumptions it had to make.

Comment: And to make everything clear, problem is solved. I just had to do this: `var price = parseFloat(row[0].cost);`

Comment: @ArnasA GODDAMNIT, seriously. You are not even using an array! Thats not an array! How can we know this? Please ask better questions next time, your entire question was unrelated to what you consider the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably put something like this:

```
var something = new Array(10)
```

but it wont loop 10 times because it's an array of 10 `undefined` values, please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach. If you assign something like this :

```
var something = [1,2,3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

it will work as expected.

Comment: Nice catch, I would add the following quote from MDN: `It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialised (i.e. on sparse arrays).`, but otherwise this would explain it.